# Can I use this Form in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, controller, twig, symfony-forms, symfony4

I have added this form in twig, i need to know if this is okay and how can i recupere the input **name="comments"** in controller

```
                <form action="{{ path('Update') }}" method="POST">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comments"
                               value=""></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
                </form>
```

Comment: I suggest you to follow tutorials about forms with symfony 4. This would be too broad to cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Symfony Request Object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object) section of the doc:

> ```
> // retrieves $_GET and $_POST variables respectively
> $request->query->get('id');
> $request->request->get('category', 'default category');
> ```

So you can retrieve in the controller as:

```
$request->request->get('comments');
```

Comment: Thank you, I have another question : I have multiple form how can i get the name of this form ?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can use the `Request` object to get all the parameters of your form, for example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Update")
 */
public function update(Request $request){
    $comments = $request->request->get('comments');
    ...    
}
```

But I recommend you to use the [forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) component.

Comment: I have multiple same form in one page, so i cant use forms component